# Implementacion HostnameVerifier Android Java Volley Seguridad PlayStore

Tags: java, android, volley

Tengo una app la cual me da el siguiente error

> HostnameVerifier Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the
>   HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how
>   resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

La cual implemento con

```
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname,SSLSession arg1)
        {                
                return true;               
        }
    });
```

este metodo esta puesto en un metodo el cual utilizo para crear todos los `objectRequest`

lo utilizo de la siguiente manera una clase con todas las colas

```
public GenericController(boolean flag) {
    objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(1, "", BaseRequest.class, "", new Response.Listener<BaseRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(BaseRequest response) {
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname,SSLSession arg1)
        {
            if (!hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("www.asdasdad.com"))
                return true;
            else
                return true;
        }
    });

}

public void servicio_Get_Bancos(final Context context, String request, final Response.Listener<Get_Bancos_IFIS> listener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    int method = Request.Method.POST;
    String serviceURL = urlInSegura;
    String req = "";
    try {
        req = request;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context,null);
        objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method, serviceURL, Get_Bancos_IFIS.class, req, listener, errorListener);
        objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "an exception was thrown", e);
    }
}
```

y de mis clases las instancio asi

```
   String rq = RequestManager.getBancos(entidadFinanciera.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim());
        GenericController gC = new GenericController(false);
        gC.servicio_Get_Bancos(context, rq, new Response.Listener<Get_Bancos_IFIS>()
```

Aun asi google me da este error alguna solucion?

Utilizo la libreria Volley

Comment: ¿Te das cuenta de que en la segunda versión, a pesar del `if`, el método siempre devuelve `true`?

Comment: @SJuan76 si me doy cuenta quiero que no me de error en playstore

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿cuál es el sentido de esto en tu app? Sugiero que leas [*Seguridad con HTTPS y SSL*](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl?hl=es-419) de la doc (está en castellano). Y para implementar algo parecido con `Volley` también puedes ver [este artículo](http://matematicainformatica.altervista.org/volley-android-https-self-signed-certificate/)  o algunas preguntas / respuestas de SO en inglés, por ejemplo [esta pregunta y alguna de sus respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17045795/5587982)

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que necesito es que no me salga la advertencia en realidad

Comment: Pero no entiendo todavía... ¿qué hace la App, muestra WebViews de varios sitios, hace llamadas a APIs de otros sitios, o qué es lo que hace?

Comment: @A.Cedano hace llamadas a mi servidor que si tiene certificados https

Comment: Esa es en parte mi confusión, o sea, ¿para qué te sirve usar `HostnameVerifier`?. Yo en mi App hago llamadas a mi servidor con Volley usando el procedimiento normal. Al inicio el dominio no era `https`, luego instalé un certificado que me ofrece el hosting gratuito y lo único que tuve que haces fue agregarle la `s` al final o sea cambiar `http` por `htpps` y no he tenido ningún tipo de problema. Me funciona tanto con JSON como con contenido HTML, ahora bien, no uso WebView, no sé si será tu caso ni sé si con ese componente daría problemas, yo presento todo en `TextView`.

Comment: @A.Cedano yo si borro este metodo de HostnameVerifier cuando lo subo a la playstore me da el error mencionado arriba que es insegura y que me falta agregar ese metodo aun poniendolo me da error, puede que yo este confundiendo cosas

Comment: No sé, es muy extraño. Es cierto que mi App está publicada antes de tener el dominio bajo SSL, en la nueva versión todas las pruebas están en `https` y no hay ninguna advertencia por ningún lado, no sé si cuando suba la nueva versión a Play Store tendré el mismo problema, ya veremos. Pero me parece extraño.

Comment: Vuestra implementacion de HostNameVerifier [de acuerdo a esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41004368/1305745) es insegura ya que remueve cualquier proteccion de https en todas las conexiones y permite que cualquiera en la red pueda acceder al contenido de vuestras comunicaciones. **Preguntas:** 1. La `urlInSegura` incluye `https`, cierto? 2. Se tiene algun certificado en la app para acceder a esos recursos por `https`?

Comment: Bruno si usas Volley normal sin `HostNameVerifier` ¿hay algún problema? Lo único es que tienes que poner `https` en vez de `http`.

Comment: ya se lo saque y anduvo lo raro es que anteriormente me paso alrevez al ponerlo no me dio mas error y si no lo teina me daba error pero ya lo tomo quien sabe

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag los url definidos deben usar https:// como comenta A.Cedano, pero preferentemente puedes también validar los certificados, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los url que debes usar deben ser cifrados, es decir utilizar:

```
https://
```

En un futuro posiblemente no se acepten urls no cifrados.

De otra forma, la correcta implementación para verificar, se debe realizar de esta forma, después de definir la conexión llama el método que realizará la verificación de los hosts:

```
...
...
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
if(url.startsWith("https")){
   trustAllHosts();
}
...
...
```

El método en el cual se define el verificador mediante `setDefaultHostnameVerifier()` sería:

```
@SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
private void trustAllHosts() {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
        SSLContext mSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[] {}; }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        }};
        mSslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(mSslContext.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class NullHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        Log.i("NullHostNameVerifier", "Aprobando certificado para hostname: " + hostname);    
        return true;
    }
}
```